# How can I add a new file/dir from a template in vifm?

Tags: templates, vifm, pcmanfm

In **pcmanfm** you can use your `~/Templates` folder, to create new files using them. it's so easy  then to make a template file and use it many times, now **VIFM** as a great file manager, ***how it can do this?***